# Subtractive blending with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I would like to for example draw shapes A, B, C then set the blender, then draw shape D and everywhere where shape D is, the scene shows my background color of (1,1,1,0). Thanks

Comment: If my source color is(1,1,1,0) then shouldnt there be a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much simpler than other answers :

- Display shapes A, B and C the normal way
- glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
- glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
- glDisable(GL_BLEND);
- Display shape D with color (1,1,1,0)

and you're done.

Comment: @Jex you may want to disable depth writes as well, depending on what you're trying to do

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of that being possible directly. There are a few possibilities to get the same effect though. The cleanest would probably be to start by filling the stencil buffer with 1's, then drawing shape D into the stencil buffer with 0's, then draw everything else (with the stencil buffer enabled, of course).

Answer (score -1):

[glBlendEquation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendEquation.xml) can do it.

Comment: That doesn't even come close to what the op is asking.

Comment: It's not? If I have a shape set to 1,1,1,0 the result of SUBTRACT operation should make the new pixel 1,1,1,0?

Comment: @Blindy The question title refers to substractive blending, but now that you mention it, the question body refers to another completely different matter.